# Concatenate text and number fields

Tags: recordtriggeredflow

[image]

Hi all I am using a flow to update a record which is a text field(Name__c).In the assignment section in the picture I am assigning a number to a variable varNum.Now I have to concatenate this number with a text "Modification" and use this combined variable in the update record and update field(Name__c) with this value Modification-01 for eg.I tried using a formula but not working.
"Modification" & " " &{!VarNum}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following situation

- a *number* variable (`VarNum`)
- Text you'd like to use (`Modification`)
- You want to combine the two as one *text* value

The obvious conflict is that you can't combine a *number* and *text* directly. Since your goal is text, you need to convert the number to text in your formula. You'll want to most likely go through [Use Text Formulas](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas/text_formulas) trailhead which covers this exact scenario:

> **TEXT()** converts a Percent, **Number**, Date, Date/Time, picklist, or Currency field into **Text**. TEXT() returns output without any formatting, commas, or currency signs

As such, just adding that should allow you to do what you want

```
"Modification-" & TEXT({!VarNum})
```

Comment: Thanks @Kris Gonclaves. Consider i have to add a lookup field as well.For eg Here my record is Grant Contract Modification and I have a related object Grant Contract.Master contract given in grant Contract Modification to Grant Contract.I can only get the name of the related field.I can only get the id if I fetch the lookup.